# AVX2 Streaming Stores Do Not Improve Performance

Tags: vectorization, avx2

I have an AVX2 implementation of some workload.

I have determined that the vast majority of the execution time is occupied
by the memory loads and stores.

In an attempt to improve performance, I tried to change the conventional stores
to streaming (non-temporal) stores.

However, this change had little to no positive performance impact (I was expecting a sizeable performance increase).

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Streaming loads/stores assume certain types of locality of reference and/or sequential access. Are you sure that your load/store pattern is one that should benefit from streaming? Also, streaming can't really make the hardware perform faster - if it takes e.g. 5 ns to load from RAM to L3 cache, it's going to take a pretty similar amount of time to load directly from RAM to register - it just bypasses the cache. You're not going to magically start getting 1 ns loads/stores...

Comment: Your program might be bounded by memory bandwidth and a lot of access to different elements suffering from huge latencies of RAM to cache and L3 to L1, etc. Find another bottleneck to improve the performance of your code, change the algorithm, optimize memory access paterns.

Comment: It's 100% sequential.  I load 48 bytes of data from an input buffer, run that through some computation and store the resulting 48 bytes in a separate buffer. Then I move on to the next sequential 48 bytes in the input buffer and repeat.

Comment: Related question (for SSE instead of AVX): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312823/when-program-will-benefit-from-prefetch-non-temporal-load-store

Answer (score 3):

The use of streaming stores can lead to a better performance under some circumstances:

1. **The data "to be stored" is not read before writing**: Streaming stores are write-through, which produces immediate bus traffic. The standard store uses a write back strategy which may delay the bus operation until a later time and avoids bus operations with multiple writes to the same cache line.
2. **The time used for stores is smaller than the time used for calculation**: A streaming store has to be finished before the next streaming store can be issued. Thus, ahving too liitle computation in between two streaming stores leads to some idle time for the processor in which no further computation can be executed. Where this problem may also be possible with standard stores, streaming stores even increase it.
3. **The data "to be stored" is not needed shortly after being written**: The streaming store surpasses caches while writing/storing. Thus, there is no copy of the data in the cache. When reading the data aftwerwards the data has to be loaded into the cache. Thus, you have no gain over a standard store. However, when using a standard store, the data is loaded into the cache, modified there, and maybe still there when a later access happens.

So you have to consider your code and problem, to these circumstances to know if streaming stores are worth a try. In an unfitting scenario your performance might even drop.

A blog entry with additional info and a benchmark can be found e.g. [here](https://blogs.fau.de/hager/archives/2103).